# Nav bar not showing up on permalink Jekyll site

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I've been toying around with a GH Pages Jekyll site. I took an HTML static site and changed the location for the stylesheet and the text/CSS.

Everything works correctly on my index.html page. However, on the other pages, the mobile/half-sized desktop navbar doesn't appear. The difference being I used a permalink to get navigate to those other pages (/categories/ instead of /categories.html).

I played around with the config file tried changing the

```yaml
permalink: /:categories/:title/
```

to

```yaml
permalink: /:categories/:title.html
```

Which gives the right filename, but it didn't address the navbar.

The only way I could fix the landing pages for the categories would be to change the links in the default.html. In this example the second item on the list works and the other doesn't.

```html
<nav id="nav">
    <a href="/TITLENAME/">Doesn't work</a>
    <a href="/test.html">Does work</a>
</nav>
```

My goal is to have permalinks. So I can seamlessly navigate from the landing page to the categories and the blog posts.

This is my GitHub repository: https://github.com/Thor-DraperJr/Thor-DraperJr.github.io

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Where exactly is the issue? `Hypertext reference` needs a to lead to a document as example an HTML document. It cant lead into a folder with no specific document to adress. If it reached that folder, it would be questionable what it should lead to. Makes logically no sense. So you either need to use variabels or use something like `.htaccess`

Comment: Ahh sorry about that.. 

So I'm thinking the issue is in the config file. I changed the _config.yml. Once I changed the permalink to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the css only was written to apply to [www.baseurl.com/page](http://www.baseurl.com/page)

I changed the permalink in the _config.yml

```yaml
permalink: /:title
```

This meant that each page and post would only show up one level past the root url.